# Обработка звонков в режиме конференц-связи

Tags: android, java

Всем привет!

Как обрабатывать ситуацию в случае когда на телефон приходит сразу несколько звонков и аппарат переколючается в режим конференц связи? (Т.е. вы не успели ответить на первый входящий, и тут же поступает второй и так далее) Через PhoneStateListener отловить поступление второго и последующих входящих не получается. Все кроме первого пролетают мимо и непонятно, как и откуда выцепить номера звонящих.
Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как это делается?

Comment: Конференц-связь - это не сервис оператора ли?

Comment: ну хз, но свм телефон на экране пишет Conference mode с отображением того что есть входящие звонки без показа номеров. и предлагает ответить на все сразу.

Comment: @Demon051 обратите внимание на количество непринятых ответов - у вас 10 вопросов и ни один не принят и даже не отмечен как полезный. Отсюда вывод: либо вы неверно задаете вопросы, либо все сообщество Хэшкод идиоты ))

Comment: :) попробую исправить, где возможно :)

кстати, а как принимать? жать на иконку с пальцем вверх?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вешайте `ContentObserver` на таблицу звонков:

```
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver
    (
      android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
      true, 
      new CallContentObserver(new Handler(), context)
    );
```

Где `CallContentObserver` класс наследующий от `ContentObserver` в нем в `onChange()` и смотрите что там у вас происходит - сколько входящих и проч.

Comment: попробую в понедельник